# RewriteRule working on http but breaks on https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some RewriteRule in htaccess to have some pretty urls for my landing page. The url can look like www.site.com/new-document and my RewriteRule will make that www.site.com/index.php?page=new-document

This way I can leave the pretty url and use index.php to change the text depending on the page variable.

Everything works perfectly well on http but once I add https to the url I get a Not Found error as in the RewriteRule is not triggering.

Here is a copy of my htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule    ^new-document$            index.php?page=new-document
RewriteRule    ^old-document$            index.php?page=old-document

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Make sure `DocumentRoot` for https site is same as http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grasshopper and anubhava pointed me in the right direction!

My problem was that the https virtual host did not have the AllowOverride All directive.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you get to the HTTPS URL without the RewriteRule?  It sounds like Apache may be using a different virtual host or not accepting HTTPS at all.